# Find the corner pixel locations of a window open on desktop in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, screenshot

I want to take a alt+screenshot of a window and input into MATLAB. Unfortunately, the screencapture code I found online only allows for you to take screencaptures of the desktop if you input the pixels you want (x,y,width,height). (well, it also allows drag-select, but that won't work in what I want to do). The link is below:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24323-screencapture-get-a-screen-capture-of-a-figure-frame-or-component

I would like to find the coordinates of a window that is on the desktop so that I can use this MATALB function and take a screenshot. 
1. Is there an automated way to find out the corner pixel locations for the window of an application that is running?
2. Is there a better MATLAB function that will allow me to just use alt+printscreen and find the screenshot directly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
pos = get(h,'position');
```

produces a a four-element vector `pos` which contains, for the Matlab window with handle `h`:

- `x` coordinate of lower-left corner
- `y` coordinate of lower-left corner
- width
- height,

all measured in pixels. As noted by @Hoki in comments, this gives the drawing area, excluding borders. If you want the full extent of the Matlab window including borders you can use

```
fullpos = get(h,'OuterPosition');
```

Comment: But what if its not a MATLAB window? Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I thought you meant a Matlab window. If that's not the case I don't know, sorry

Comment: @LooYung - You would need to access OS system-level information if you want to do that, which can't be done natively in MATLAB.  I'm assuming you're using Windows as you are referencing the use of the `Alt` key.  If you're using Windows, you have no choice but to use the Windows API - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633519(v=vs.85).aspx ... which of course, cannot be done natively in MATLAB.

Comment: @LuisMendo, although this is not enough for the OP anyway, you should also mention `fullpos = get(h,'OuterPosition');` to get the full extent of the matlab figure including borders (not just the drawing area).